# How to add a custom action button column to a list?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath, sharepoint-designer, infopath2010

I need to keep lists that contains lots of links and i want my users to have the ability to report a broken link by a button that will be located on each row.

So far i managed to create a custom form using InfoPath that does the trick, but the button only appears in the edit/add new item windows in SharePoint. And i would like it to appear in a column of its own with a button in each row.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a "column of it's own" but if you set your custom action location to editcontrolblock it will appear in the context menu when you click a list item. If your interrested in that, go on this page there's an xml example there http://www.dotnetmikael.com/2012/09/sharepoint-2010-renaming-listitems.html